# Why isn't converted think script code working?

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I hope everyone is having an amazing day. I am having problems converting my think script code into pine script. I understand the basics of pine script but I cant seem to figure why I'm having errors with my code. Every time I plot it an error pops up "mismatched input 'then' expecting 'end of line without line continuation". My goal is to turn the Variable EMA indicator from think script into a variable ema in pine script. I  will list both the think script indicator code and the pine script code that I have attempted to convert down below. Any form of help is greatly appreciated.

think script Variable EMA code:

```
"input price = close;input length = 10; def tmp1 = if price > price[1] then price - price[1] else 0;def tmp2 = if price[1] > price then price[1] - price else 0;def d2 = sum(tmp1, length);def d4 = sum(tmp2, length);def cond = d2 + d4 == 0;def ad3 = if cond then 0 else (d2 - d4) / (d2 + d4) * 100;def coeff = 2 / (length + 1) * AbsValue(ad3) / 100;def asd = compoundValue("visible data" = coeff * price + (if IsNaN(asd[1]) then 0 else asd[1]) * (1 - coeff), "historical data" = price
);plot VMA = asd;"
```

Pine script (attempted converted) Variable EMA code

```
//@version=5//VARIABLEMOVINGAVERAGE length = input.int(10, title= "length") tmp1= input  (if close > close[1] then close - close[1] else 0) tmp2 = input (if close[1] > close then close[1] - close else 0) d2 = input (sum(tmp1, length)) d4 = input (sum(tmp2, length)) cond = input (d2 + d4 == 0) ad3 = input (if cond then 0 else (d2 - d4) / (d2 + d4) * 100) coeff = input (2 / (length + 1) * AbsValue(ad3) / 100) asd = input (compoundValue "visible data" = coeff * close + (if IsNaN(asd[1]) then 0 else asd[1]) * (1 - coeff), "historical data" = close) plot1 = plot VMA == asd"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Variable Moving Average", overlay = true)

length = input.int(10, title= "length")
tmp1 = close > close[1] ? close - close[1] : 0
tmp2 = close[1] > close ? close[1] - close : 0
d2 = math.sum(tmp1, length)
d4 = math.sum(tmp2, length)
cond = d2 + d4 == 0
ad3 = cond ? 0 : (d2 - d4) / (d2 + d4) * 100
coeff = 2 / (length + 1) * math.abs(ad3) / 100

float asd = na
asd := coeff * close + nz(asd[1], 0) * (1 - coeff)

plot1 = plot(asd)
```

Comment: I really appreciate this!! It worked perfectly !!